# eclipse crashes - failed to start jvm

Tags: android, eclipse, jvm, weka, jvm-crash

i am trying to use weka on Android. i need to increase the heapspace to use that. i have tried various combinations of -xmx and -xms but it fails to start the jvm.
currently i have this set up, but it does not work

> --launcher.XXMaxPermSize 1024m
>   -vmargs
>   -Xms256m
>   -Xmx1024m

currently i have a 64bit arch machine, but 32bit Win 7 installed on it. 4gb memory.
kindly advise

Comment: Try starting it in debug mode and see if there are any errors: `eclipse -debug -consoleLog`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with memory space fragmentation caused by Windows dll loading. Only two workarounds if Eclipse fails to start with higher memory settings.

1. Install 64-bit Windows and use 64-bit JVM with 64-bit Eclipse. It doesn't matter that you only have 4gb of memory. Having 64-bit virtual memory space prevents you from running into fragmentation issues.
2. Force eclipse to start with java.exe or javaw.exe instead of the default jvm.dll startup. To do this, edit eclipse.ini and add -vm followed with a full path to javaw.exe on the next line.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. What i did was, open **Eclipse** as **Admin** and it worked properly.